# Sampling histograms such that the sum over the sample is uniform

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, sampling

I have a list of items from which I want to randomly sample a subset, but each item is paired with a histogram over D bins and I want to sample the items in such a way that the summed histogram is approximately uniform.

Thus it should work as the sample function below:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> #The histograms from which to sample (each having 5 bins):
>>> data = numpy.random.randint(100, size=(10000,5))
>>> #The function which I'm trying to program:
>>> samples = sample(data,500)
>>> samples.shape
(500,5)
>>> summed_histogram = samples.sum(axis=0)
>>> #Each bin should have approximately equal value
>>> summed_histogram / float(summed_histogram.sum())
array([ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2])
```

The absolute values of the summed histogram are not important nor does it need to be exactly uniform, it just needs to be approximately uniform. Also, I don't care if the returned sample size is not exactly the specified sample size. The sampling should be without replacement.

Comment: As an aside, the items that I want to sample are image patches and the histogram are label histograms from a manual segmentation of the image.

Comment: What you could do is first choose weights for your items so as to make the weighted sum (approximately) uniform, and then take a weighted sample of the items. The first part is a multivariate optimization problem, the second is relatively straightforward e.g. using `cumsum()` to compute the CDF and `searchsorted()` to sample it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @Ilmari Karonen's solution, what you want to do is compute weights for each histogram and then sample according to those weights. It appears to me that the most efficient way to do this, given your goal, would be with a [linear program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming).

Let D_ij be the weight of the jth bin in the histogram of the ith item. Then if each item is weighted with weight w_i, the "summed histogram" would have weight sum(i in items) w_i D_ij. One way to get your "approximately uniform" distribution would be to minimize the maximum difference across bins, so we would solve the following LP:

```
minimize z
subject to (for all j, k) 
    z >= (sum i in items) w_i D_ij - (sum i in items) w_i D_ik
    z >= (sum i in items) w_i D_ik - (sum i in items) w_i D_ij
```

The above is basically saying that `z >=` absolute value of difference across all weighted pairs of bins. To solve this LP you will need a separate package since numpy does not include a LP solver. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mizzao/4961762) for a solution using `cplex` or [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cvanweelden/4961033) for a solution using `cvxpy`. Note that you will need to set some constraints on the weights (e.g. each weight is larger or equal to 0) as these solutions do. Other python bindings for GLPK (GNU Linear Programming kit) can be found here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Python.

Finally you just sample from histogram `i` with weight `w_i`. This can be done with an adaptation of roulette selection using `cumsum` and `searchsorted` as suggested by @Ilmari Karonen, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cvanweelden/4971289).

If you wanted the resulting weighted distribution to be "as uniform as possible", I would solve a similar problem with weights, but maximize the weighted entropy across the weighted sum of bins. This problem would appear to be nonlinear although you could use any number of nonlinear solvers such as BFGS or gradient-based methods. This would probably be a bit slower than the LP method but it depends on what you need in your application. The LP method would approximate the nonlinear method very closely if you have a large number of histograms, because it would be easy to reach a uniform distribution.

When using the LP solution, a bunch of the histogram weights may bind to 0 because the number of constraints is small, but this will not be a problem with a non-trivial number of bins, since the number of constraints is O(n^2).

Example weights with 50 histograms and 10 bins:

```
[0.006123642775837011, 0.08591660144140816, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03407525280610657, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.07092537493489116, 0.0, 0.0, 0.023926802333318554, 0.0, 0.03941537854267549, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10937063438351756, 0.08715770469631079, 0.0, 0.05841899435928017, 0.016328676622408153, 0.002218517959171183, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.08186919626269101, 0.03173286609277701, 0.08737065271898292, 0.0, 0.0, 0.041505225727435785, 0.05033635148761689, 0.0, 0.09172214842175723, 0.027548495513552738, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0259929997624099, 0.0, 0.0, 0.028044483157851748, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

With 50 histograms each with 50 bins, now very few zero values:

```
[0.0219136051655165, 0.0, 0.028325808078797768, 0.0, 0.040889043180965624, 0.04372501089775975, 0.0, 0.031032870504105477, 0.020745831040881676, 0.04794861828714149, 0.0, 0.03763592540998652, 0.0029093177405377577, 0.0034239051136138398, 0.0, 0.03079554151573207, 0.0, 0.04676278554085836, 0.0461258666541918, 9.639105313353352e-05, 0.0, 0.013649362063473166, 0.059168272186891635, 0.06703936360466661, 0.0, 0.0, 0.03175895249795131, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04376133487616099, 0.02406633433758186, 0.009724226721798858, 0.05058252335384487, 0.0, 0.0393763638188805, 0.05287112817101315, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06365320629437914, 0.0, 0.024978299494456246, 0.023531082497830605, 0.033406648550332804, 0.012693750980220679, 0.00274892002684083, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.04465971034045478, 4.888224154453002]
```

Comment: This seems to be the way to go. I'll give it a try before accepting it as answer though.

Comment: Great, let me know if I can help with anything. I've used both LP and nonlinear solvers from Java for many applications.

Comment: I had to add the constraint that all `w >= 0`, after that I got it working, see this gist for the problem in `cvxpy`: https://gist.github.com/cvanweelden/4961033

Comment: I updated the post with my response. Sorry that my python knowledge is pretty bad.

Comment: OK...while you were doing that, I spent an hour trying to learn python :D

Comment: Haha, sorry, that is what you get for responding to a question tagged numpy and python. ;) Thank you! For now I'll stick to the cvxpy version since I already had cvxopt as a dependency and it has a more permissive license. Also it doesn't seem too slow for a large number of constraints and I don't get the problem with 0 weights as much. I'll figure out roulette selection without replacement on Sunday and accept your answer once I've seen the results. :)

Comment: I see. cvxopt uses LP libraries from GLPK already, so that is probably the solver that is used. (I thought it was different from cvxpy.) For random weighted selection, that's easy; check out `selectRandomWeighted` on this page: https://github.com/mizzao/libmao/blob/master/src/main/java/net/andrewmao/math/RandomSelection.java; it is an adaptation of the stream selection algorithm for the weighted case.

Comment: I incorporated your changes from the rejected edit into this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you draw a number of complete random samples (of 500), and then pick the one that is most uniform (i.e. lowest `sample.sum(axis=0).std()`)? That avoids weird biases when drawing incremental samples.

Comment: The problem with this is that the probability of any one of those samples having a distribution that is very different from the dataset distribution is extremely small. The number of samples I would have to draw in order to have a good chance at drawing an approximately uniform sample would be way too large.